# How to change the display of subfigures in List of Figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats, subcaption

I'm using the `subcaption` package and I would like to change the display in the List of Figures of the subfigures.

Right now, it displays as :

```
2.1 Caption 1  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
   a      Subcaption 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
   b      Subcaption 2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
```

I'd like it to have a display as :

```
2.1  Caption . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
   2.1.a  Subcaption 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
   2.1.b  Subcaption 2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
```

Is it possible to customize the display ?

Here's the a piece of code I'm using :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{subfigure1.jpg}
\caption{subcaption 1}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{subfigure2.jpg}
\caption{subcaption 2}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:fig} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use the option `listformat=...`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\section{One}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{subfigure1.jpg}
\caption{subcaption 1}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{subfigure2.jpg}
\caption{subcaption 2}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:fig} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have an additional dot between figure and sub-figure number, one option is creating an own list format, e.g.:

```
...
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{myfmt}{#1.#2}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=myfmt]{subcaption}
...
```

[image]

Please note that this solution will still give you references like `1.1a` as result of `\ref{fig:sub1}`.

To change both, the appearance of List of Figures, and the references, one better re-define `\p@subcaption`. For example:

```
...
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\p@subfigure{.}
\makeatother
...
```

As opposite to the last solution this one will change both to `1.1.a`, i.e. having a period between figure and sub-figure part of the numbering in List of Figures and references.

(For details about `listformat=` and `\DeclareCaptionListFormat` please take a look at the `caption` package documentation. For details about `\p@subfigure` please take a look at the `subcaption` package documentation, section "References".)