# how to include subfigures in list of figures or sub tables in the list of tables

Tags: tables, subfloats, subcaption

Currently, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` display only the root and not the sub parts. I there any way to make them display sub parts as well? I tried searching but found nothing that I can use which works.

Comment: Does this question/answer help http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97094/31058? Are you using the `[list=true]` option with the `subcaption` package?

Comment: No, but busing it made no difference

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is here. you'll have to set the maximum depth of the list of figures and the list of tables. If not, then the default is one.

For list of figures just write this at the beginning of the document

```
\setcounter{lofdepth}{depth number}  %\replace depth number with an integer number
```

As for the list of tables:

```
\setcounter{lotdepth}{depth number}
```