# Custom text alignment

Tags: environments, alignment, text-manipulation

Is there an option to define custom alignment for text? For example, to make your own `\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}`?

In particular, I want to have an alignment (for text) that it is centred when there is only one line, but is left-aligned when it needs to have more than one line (i.e. when there is a linebreak).
Of course, this can be done manually, but this doesn't sound very convenient.

Comment: Caption uses a single line;check.  It puts the text into an \hbox and measures the width.  If too wide, it uses paragraph formatting.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't understand what you mean. What is "caption"?

Comment: \caption is used by floats (figure & table) to 1) increment the figure number, 2) label the float and 3) add an entry into the list  of figures.  It is part of standard LaTeX, but a much fancier version is available in the caption package.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have the same effect as `\caption` with `singlelinecheck`, but for, say, a `minipage` instead?

Comment: Of course it is possible.   It would look like wipet's solution, only using an `\hbox` and `\ifdim\wd0>\columnwidth`.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233687/how-not-to-show-caption-of-figure-but-only-of-subfigure-in-list-of-figures/233724#233724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comments and answers here I made this code which uses the `environ` package:

```
\usepackage{environ}

\environbodyname\yourinput

\NewEnviron{autocentredtext}{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\yourinput}
    \ifdim\wd0<\textwidth
    \begin{center}
    \yourinput
    \end{center}
    \fi
    \noindent\yourinput
}%[\ignorespacesafterend]
```

This creates an *environment* which is implemented by `\begin{autocentredtext}...\end{autocentredtext}` which first reads your *text* input, checks if it's shorter than `\textwidth`, and if it is, it gets centred or otherwise it becomes non-indented.

One might want to add `[\ignorespacesafterend]` at the end of the above code to fix some possible spacing issues.

---

Unfortunately, it seems that this cannot be used with `\newenvironment`. For example,

```
\newenvironment{autocentering}{\begin{autocentredtext}}{\end{autocentredtext}}
```

creates an error. If one uses `\NewEnviron` instead of `\newenvironment`, they should be able to overcome this.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can define the macro `\centeredpar` as follows:

```
\def\centeredpar #1\par{\noindent
   \setbox0 =\vbox{\noindent #1\par
   \expandafter}\ifnum\prevgraf=1 \hfil \else \indent \fi 
   #1\par 
}

% test

\centeredpar Short text.

\centeredpar Long text. Sgsh jk k kk fr j ewh ej wwu ye ew gh
             hq hhad hj adj, had j dahj.
             Sgsh jk k k tuiu iwe huwi tyac  hq hhad hj adj, had j dahj.

% text of \centeredpar must be finished by empty line.
```

The paragraph is typeset into working `\vbox` and the number of paragraph lines i measured by `\prevgraf` TeX primitive. The `\hfil` primitive adds a glue before the real paragraph. The end of paragraph is processed by internal TeX algorithm, with `\parfillskip` register which has the same "force" as `\hfil` by default. So, the text is centered. Else `\indent` is added and multiline pararagraph is printed. You can omit `\indent` in this macro if you need not to start with the `\indent`.

Comment: Is it possible to make such an environment and make it work with math?

Comment: @antshar Please, be more clear what is your intent. Maybe, you can open new thread. If you mean that TeX will automatically break long display formula the I mean that this is not so simple and it is against the intent of TeX: user have to decide where break points are in math formula because automaton is not able to understand the formula well.

Comment: I cannot say I understand this completely, but I like this solution.

I think `\else \indent` can be entirely omitted and there will no problem, right?

Also, `\vbox{...}` is there just to count the lines? Because it seems that it isn't printed in the .pdf.

Finally, can you explain at which point `\ifnum` stops expanding to let `\expandafter` bring back the `}` token?

Comment: Another question: It seems that `\centeredpar` gives an error if I try to use it inside a custom environment, for example `\newenvironment{textcentered}{\centeredpar}{}`

Comment: @Jim 1) `\else\indent` can be omited. 2. `\setbox0=\vbox{...}` means that the typesetting material is saved to box 0, no printed. The box 0 is not used later, may be other macro use `\setbox0=`, then the contents is over-writen (this does no matter). The `\vbox` closes group when it finishes, so I meant that the `\expandafter` is needed. But more true is that it is not needed because `\prevgraph` is special primitive register with global value only.

Comment: @Jim Another answer: `\centeredpar` needs to be finished by empty line or `\par`. You can declare another separator or incorporate it to the LaTeX environment. Why to do? It depends on principles of LaTeX environments. I don't use LaTeX so I don't know these principles precisely.